# How to integrate in Python inside For loop

Tags: python-2.7, math, scipy

I would like to use scipy's integrate.simps to get a integrated function from a data sample.

Data sample is getting calculated inside For loop (variable fx).
In the same step I store integrated values in the variable intfx.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from scipy import integrate

t=np.arange(0,10.01,0.01)

fx=[]
intfx=[]

counter=0
for i in t:
    counter+=1
    fx.append(np.sin(i))
    intfx.append(fx[-1]+integrate.trapz(fx[-2:], dx=0.1))

pl.plot(t,fx)
pl.plot(t,intfx)
pl.show()
```

On plots it can be seen that the two functions are very similar, which is obviously wrong.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a stupid mistake.

Line:

```
intfx.append(fx[-1]+integrate.trapz(fx[-2:], dx=0.1))
```

should look like this:

```
intfx.append(intfx[-1]+integrate.trapz(fx[-2:], dx=0.1))
```